# what does the white umbrella above java.class icon mean in IDEA?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android project there is a white mark or icon above the java.class:

[image]

what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a `Pin` icon, not `umbrella`

### The java class has a Pin because that declared as a final class

I think you have declared your `LiveRecipient` as a final class

[image]

for more information please check [**Icon reference**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html)